# Optimizing binary app size on iPhone / iPod touch

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

I know that a user can only download up to 20MB over 3G, and my build/Release-iphoneos is showing my app at 26MB.

I'm linking against the three20 iPhone framework.

Is this the final size that will count against the 20MB max when submitted to the App Store?

Is there anything I can do squeeze this even lower?  (I'm using a bunch of PNG's converted from JPEG, so I guess I can lower the quality they're being converted at.)

Thanks.

Comment: If the images were originally JPEGs, they will probably be more compact as JPEGs than PNGs.

Comment: should I be using the jpegs then?  I thought Apple recommends PNGs instead.

Comment: if the question is specific to image resource compression, it doesn't have to do with the *binary* size. perhaps the question should be renamed, or you could provide us with actual figures: 18MB of 26 are binary, 4 MB are xibs, 4 MB are images (although an unlikely ratio). Image resource compression is much different from binary size reduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that you're actually fine. What actually matters is the app size once it's been compressed, as that's how Apple sends the apps as well. Right(control)-click on your release app and choose Compress. The size of the resulting .zip file is what needs to be less than 20MB.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some kind of sound??? if you are be careful with the format you are using,(in my case, sound is always my biggest problem refering to app size)

And yes, the binary size will be your app size in the appstore too

Comment: well then try to resize the pngs or lowe the quality, and dont add anything you are not using to the app :)

Answer (score 0):

How big is the binary itself? I doubt it contributes much to overall size of the app bundle. Consider using `pngcrush` ([here](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/)) on those PNG files. Resources are going to be the biggest place you can make a saving.

Comment: I thought pngcrush (or equivalent) is already run by apple's installation/packaging script?  I will try running it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the three20 sdk will increase your app size also (about 1-2M with **-all_load** flag).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 24-bit PNGs, then you can halve their size with [ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com).

However, if your original images were JPEGs, then keep them in that format, as it doesn't make sense to convert lossy format to lossless (that just inflates the file size without restoring any quality).