# (iphone) what's included in application binary, and how to view the size of it?

Tags: iphone, xcode, binary, size, organizer

I'd like my app be under 20Mb limit.

[Old posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922719/optimizing-binary-app-size-on-iphone-ipod-touch) talk about zipping an app and see the file size.
But archiving through xcode4, and submitting through organizer doesn't show the file.

Archive file listed in organizer is *.xarchive format,(I'm not sure this is equivalent of the zip file in the past) and mine shows 45mb.
And it's taking insanely long to submit the archive(about 2 hours).

I checked the app size when I used xcode3, and it was about 16mb and something should have been messed up.

Related question is:

1. When my app's project directory is
   MyAppDirectory, does everything
   under that directory gets included
   in the binary or just stuff which I
   add to the project in xcode?
2. I copy images/sound files to
   Resources using "copy files" in
   "Build phases", does that make the
   same images/sound files to be
   included in the binary twice?(how do
   I check?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you made archive go to the Organizer and select share. Then create the ipa from there, the ipa is the (about) size of the app when you have uploaded it to the appstore.

1. No and Yes, all non source files that have been added to the target will be copied into the .app folder (iOS apps are just folders). All the source code files will be compiled into an binary which is also included in the .app folder. Then this gets zipped and then renamed to .ipa (with the .app folder in a director calles 'Payload').
2. No, all files a copied once to the .app folder, if it get copied twice you will receive a warning, but if you use folders and the same fil is in multiple folders in your project then it will be copied multiple times (for each folder) into the .app

You can easily see if you have folders in your project, they a blue folder instead of Yellow which are groups.

Comment: thanks, questions remain though, why *.xarchives are about 3 times bigger than my *.ipa file, and why is it taking that long to upload the file?

Comment: .xarchives contains more than just your app, it also contains debug information. A 1mb app will taken (I my case) any where from 1 to 4 min. to upload. I've got no real explanation for this.